# how to change UIImageVIew from appdelegate in Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiimageview

I have a problem. I'm trying change an `UIImageView` from `appDelegate` with a `NSNotificationCenter` function but I get an error. When I change this from `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function with the `NSNotificationCenter` I get an `Exc_Breakpoint`

In AppDelegate:

```
  var classView: ViewController!

 func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool {
       NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "myFunction:" ....
 }

 func myFunction(note: NSNotofication){
      classView.myImageView.image = UIImage(named: "picture1") //Here get the crash
  }
```

How can I call correctly and change the `UIImageView` from `appDelegate`?

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: try adding the image type after picture1 e.g. UIImage(named:"picture1.png");

Answer (score 0):

Post notification from the view controller and pass the imageView inside the userInfo of notification and in app delegate extract the imageView and set image to it like this,

```
class ViewController: UIViewController{

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: view.bounds)
    self.view.addSubview(imageView)

    // post notification and pass imageview in userInfo

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("MySetImageViewNotification", object: nil, userInfo: ["imageView": imageView])
  }
}
```

And in app delegate, you would observe for the notification, extract the imageview and set image to it like this,

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

  func application(application: UIApplication!, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary!) -> Bool {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "setImageViewNotification:", name: "MySetImageViewNotification", object: nil)
    return true
  }

  func setImageViewNotification(note: NSNotification){
    let userInfo = note.userInfo as [String: UIImageView]
    let imageView = userInfo["imageView"]
    imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "image.png")
  }
}
```

Comment: why am I getting an Exc_breakpoint in this line:let userInfo = note.userInfo as [String: UIImageView]?

Comment: There aren't question mark on my code, is for make my question here, my code is: let userInfo = note.userInfo as [String: UIImageView]

Comment: What could be the problem? If I use reachability in the NS Notification (kReachabilityChangedNotification), I get the error in Reachability .m class too, in line:
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: kReachabilityChangedNotification object: noteObject];

Comment: Do you have an exception breakpoint active? Try disabling breakpoints and see if you get the exception message